# How to collect multiple related properties in a single backing bean property?

Tags: jsf, collections, jsf-2

Is there a way to replace this in backing bean

```
private int room1ad
private int room1ch
private int room1ch1
private int room1ch2
private int room1ch3
private int room1ch4
// getters & setters
```

and this in the view

```
<h:form>
  <h:selectOneMenu value="#{hotelsController.room1ad}">
      <f:selectItem itemLabel="1" itemValue="1"/>
      <f:selectItem itemLabel="2" itemValue="2"/>
      <f:selectItem itemLabel="3" itemValue="3"/>
  </h:selectOneMenu>
  <h:selectOneMenu value="#{hotelsController.room1ch}">
      <f:selectItem itemLabel="1" itemValue="1"/>
      <f:selectItem itemLabel="2" itemValue="2"/>
      <f:selectItem itemLabel="3" itemValue="3"/>
  </h:selectOneMenu>
  <h:selectOneMenu value="#{hotelsController.room1ch1}">
      <f:selectItem itemLabel="1" itemValue="1"/>
      <f:selectItem itemLabel="2" itemValue="2"/>
      <f:selectItem itemLabel="3" itemValue="3"/>
 </h:selectOneMenu>
 ......
 </h:form>
```

This doesn't look so bad, but I have 10 rooms in one backing bean.

I thought about something like this in backing bean

```
//BB
private Room room1
```

And the view basically the same, but it would create object after submition
so the way it works instead of having 6 ints for each room in BB I would only have x Room classes inside and XHTML form would make directly POJO instead of accessing individually each `int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EL supports lists and properties on POJOs, so you could easily use it:

```
public List<Room> getRooms();
```

and xhtml:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{hotelsController.rooms}" var="room">
  <h:selectOneMenu value="#{room.ad}">
      <f:selectItem itemLabel="1" itemValue="1"/>
      <f:selectItem itemLabel="2" itemValue="2"/>
      <f:selectItem itemLabel="3" itemValue="3"/>
  </h:selectOneMenu>
  .
  .
</ui:repeat>
```

Comment: yes but i need to define number of rooms before right? but i have one selectOne to define number of rooms. but im going to try your sollution.

Comment: @Mazmart It is hard to guess what your business requirements are just from xhtml so maybe my snippet does not fit perfectly. My intention was more to demonstrate possible options.

Comment: No it works perfectly :) thank you. last thing is i want to write for each iteration of `<ui:repeat>` `<h:outputText value="Room X(1,2,3)"/>`

Comment: @Mazmart You can either nest another ui:repeat - if it makes sense - or simply go for `<h:outputText value="#{room.x(1)}/>. It is still more of guessing for me since I didn't grasp your particular case.